# Comma around adjectives

Tags: punctuation, parenthetical-commas

Is there a comma error in this sentence?

> He wrote other, more insidious, books.

I was told that the comma after insidious is improper. It is, I say, perfectly acceptable usage. Am I in error here?

Comment: It could be argued that "more insidious" is a "parenthetical expression".

Comment: It depends on the intended meaning. Is "other" intended to modify "more insidious", or is it intended that "other" and "more insidious" jointly modify "books".

Answer (score -1):

There exists a test for determining with a fairly good chance of success whether a comma is necessary between adjectives; it is found [here](https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/commas-between-adjectives/).

> - First, place the word "and" between the two adjectives.
> - Second, reverse them.
>   If, in both instances, the resulting phrase still sounds appropriate, we are most likely dealing with coordinate adjectives and should use a comma between them.

When you have a minimum habit of the language you can use that test; I figure that  for a certain time period (which I couldn't determine) it is of little use to beginners.

You can say, very apparently¹, "other **and** more insidious books"; but you can't say  "more insidious other books". Therefore it is probable that you shouldn't use a comma.

This is strictly confirmed by the examples that can be obtained from the books. Here is a list of combinations of the same type found in Google books.

[other more  recent  books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20recent%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more  advanced  books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20advanced%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more  detailed  books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20detailed%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more   specialized books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20specialized%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more   technical books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20technical%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more   general books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20general%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more   modern books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20modern%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more  important  books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20important%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more   comprehensive books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20comprehensive%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
     [other more   serious books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20more%20serious%20books%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

---

*¹ Correction due to a comment of **[user Abcderia](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564617/comma-around-adjectives/564618?noredirect=1#comment1397744_564618)'s***: '[…] I do think you can say "other and more insidious books." Is it not a parenthetical when enclosed with commas, and just a slightly old-school stylistic tic?'.

A research on Google books with "*other and more * §*" replacing successively "§" by the nouns in the two lists below, yielded nothing for the first one but plenty of results for the second.

- "books", "attitudes", "intentions", "cars", "outlooks", "pupils"
- "thoughts", "worries", "ways",  "means",  "people","responsibilities"

*Results*

- thoughts: special, agreeable, solemn, painful, serious, important
   - worries: serious
   - ways: effective, important, subtle, direct, recondite, profitable, satisfactory, practical,                  serious, effectual
   - means: efficient, direct, certain, powerful, simple, accurate, effectual, legitimate, effective,                     economical
   - people: designing, fortunate, important
   - responsibilities: pressing, important

As a consequence of this outcome, I think that there is no problem saying or writing "other and more insidious books".

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful, and I appreciate the research. But I do think you can say "other and more insidious books." Is it not a parenthetical when enclosed with commas, and just a slightly old-school stylistic tic?

Comment: @Abcderia I made a modification according to your remarks. If you think certain additional details would be interesting, feel free to make me aware of them. As you can't yet make additions (or corrections) to someone's answer (2000 points needed for that), I'll have to do that myself.

Comment: Parentheticals are in essence asides, comments, afterthoughts ... rather than 'strings set off by commas, dashes, brackets or ellipses'. Indeed, on occasion zero punctuation is quite acceptable.

Comment: But  _other more modern books_ = _other [more modern books]_: 'She found a large stack of more modern books in the second room, then 3 other more modern books in the attic.' WHILE _other, more modern{,} books_ = _other books, which were more modern than those already mentioned_: 'She found other, more modern{,} books in the second room.' // The comma after _modern_ here? I'd say it's optional. It marks off what is essentially a parenthetical (adding detail: two brackets could equally well be used around _more modern_) but clutters and isn't really necessary to clarify. Minimalism is OK.